# Woocommerce Edit Message "An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in."

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to overwrite this message via `functions.php` through a child's theme. I have seen some examples through [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-this-message-on-the-checkout-page/) and [here](https://www.checkoutwc.com/).

I would prefer using a filter but don't know why is it not working when I add it into `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', function( $html ) {
    $url =  wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
    $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_checkout', 1, $url );
    $html = str_replace( 'Please log in', '<a href="'.$url.'"><strong>Please log in</strong></a>', $html );
    return $html;
} );
```

Comment: Hi I tested your code on my own website and it seems to work perfectly.  It makes the "Please log in" bold and clickable. What exactly are the issues you are running into?

Comment: Hi @John, it is working now. Just forgot to clean cache.

Comment: @John , so it replaces the login string with a link. Is there a way to completely change it to a custom text instead of saying please login?

Comment: Yeah very simply change it to what you want in this line, for example: `$html = str_replace( 'Please log in', '<a href="'.$url.'"><strong>PUT WHATEVER TEXT YOU WANT HERE</strong></a>', $html );`

Comment: I posted an answer with the full code if you are looking to replace the entire message with something else, not just the "please log in" part. Take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the change the entire message, use this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', function( $html ) {
    $url =  wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
    $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_checkout', 1, $url );
    $html = str_replace( 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in', '<a href="'.$url.'"><strong>YOUR CUSTOM TEXT</strong></a>', $html );
    return $html;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (put in your functions.php):

```
/** Replace 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in.' **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', function() {
    return 'Este înregistrat deja un cont cu adresa ta de e-mail. <a href="#" class="showlogin">Te rugăm să te autentifici.</a>';
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete html code includes the anchor tag as well. Add this filter in functions.php file in child theme. You can change the TEXTs as desired.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', function( $html ) {
    $html = str_replace( 'An account is already registered with your email address. <a href="#" class="showlogin">Please log in.</a>', 'TEXT1. <a href="#" class="showlogin">TEXT2.</a>', $html );
    return $html;
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by changing the line of code in the `woocommerce\includes\wc-user-functions.php file. =>Line 47.`

after this code

```
if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-email-exists', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_error_email_exists', __( 'An account is already registered with your email address. <a href="#" class="showlogin">Please log in.</a>', 'woocommerce' ), $email ) );
}
```